# Window.scroll() method only working on hard reload, but not onMount() in Svelte

Tags: javascript, css, svelte, sveltekit

I am trying to set my window to a particular place everytime a particular component is mounted. I am using `window.scroll()` and `onMount()` handler for this.

```
    onMount(() => {
        window.scroll({
            top: 400,
            left: 100,
            behavior: "smooth",
        })
    })
```

The problem is that the function only works when I manually reload the page in the browser, and not when I actually navigate to the page in my sveltekit app.

I modified the function to indicate whether onMount is indeed working:

```
    onMount(() => {
        window.scroll({
            top: 400,
            left: 100,
            behavior: "smooth",
        })
        console.log("Page Mounted!")
    })

    onDestroy(() => {
        console.log("Page Unmounted!")
    })
```

`console.log()` always works as expected but not `window.scroll()`. What could be the problem here?

Comment: Might have to do with SvelteKit's own scroll handling, which might undo your scroll operation. Does adding data-sveltekit-noscroll on the links have any effect? https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/link-options#data-sveltekit-noscroll

Comment: @BobFanger `data-sveltekit-noscroll` doesn't seem to have any effect, unfortunately.

Comment: What are you using to navigate ? Simple <a> elements or goto() ?

Comment: @camb I'm using <a> elements

Comment: does wrapping scroll in a SetTimeout() changes anything ?

Comment: @camb SetTimeout() did the trick. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, wrapping `window.scroll()` in a `setTimeout()` fixed this issue.